# SSIS package breaks accented characters on SELECT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server SSIS package that inserts data in a table according to data in another table. The thing is this job breaks the accents of the `varchar` data in the process. I suppose it has something to do with encoding.

Simplified, my package does the following :

- Select data with an OLE DB Source through SQL command data access mode

  ```
  SELECT id, name, lastname
  FROM Client 
  <WHERE id = 1>
  ```
- Insert the selected data with an OLE DB Destination through mapping to `ClientCopy` table.

I noticed that previewing the data in the first step was returning me the broken accents already. Because of this, the data inserted in ClientCopy obviously has those broken accents.

```
id name  lastname
1  Andr‚ BriŠre
```

This same query when executed in SQL Server returns the data correctly so I'm a bit lost right now.

```
id name  lastname
1  André Brière
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: This could be a "varchar-vs-nvarchar" issue, or a code-page / encoding issue. Do the databases have the same Collation - if not, what are their collations?

Comment: @LaughingVergil I thought so too initially but the "preview data" confused me. Previewing the select's data was already giving broken accents results. That's before inserting into the copy table. Though a simple SELECT in MSSQL returns accented characters just fine.

Comment: What is your package written in? Is it an ADODB, ODBC, or ?? connection to the database?

Comment: Don't rely on the preview - that mightn't be whats really coming through the data flow. What's the data types and collation of the source and target fields? If you do 'Show Advanced Editor' on the source and targets, go to input and output properties, what kind of data types do you see? If they are NVARCHAR and DT_WSTR throughout you shouldn't have a problem. If these tables are on the same SQL Server then you can just run an INSERT/SELECT and not have to deal with SSIS data types at all

Comment: If you check the metadata settings of your source (e.g. by right-clicking the arrow ans select metadata), what does it say for the specific column? Varchar or nvarchar? Sometimes SSIS doesnt't recognize the source correctly and messes up the types... at least this was my impression when working with it.